How do I take apart Wellgo pedal (to lubricate bearings)?
I want to take apart a pedal on my sons Frog 55 kid's bike as there is play in the pedal and it is squeaking. While I am at it, I want to re-grease the bearings.
I am, however, not able to figure out how to take apart the pedal and get to the spindle and the bearings. I have popped off the plastic cover but instead of a locknut there is only a round metal thingy. I am not able to fit a tool on this round metal thingy and therefore I cannot free the spindle.
Any ideas?
I have attached some photos. Hopefully, they give an idea of my issue.







May be a matter of personal taste but I find rubber pedals much more comfortable for a casual bike (no hooks or bike shoes).

The pedals are not designed to be serviced.
I've had some success using a light oil on the bearings of pedals like this. If I'm trying to clean the bearings I over oil hoping to flush out dirt and then clean up the mess.
You can either live with the play or replace the pedals.

Been there - same experience.  These are unserviceable pedals, often with a staked-over axle instead of a removable fastener.   They can be improved by getting oil in there somehow.

Thanks, that's good to know. I will try to get some light oil in there.

If the end has simply been staked over, it implies that the metal is relatively soft. The play might not be a bearing, but in between a bearing and other metal components. Could possibly be fixed with Locktite, but getting in would require a hacksaw... which somehow seems to defeat the point...

@MarkMorganLloyd There is a chance that the axle is selectively hardened (as in, the end is left soft to allow for  staking whereas the rest of the axle is hard), but I do think it’s somewhat more likely that the whole thing is just cheap soft steel.

You sure that's got a serviceable bearing n it? it looks like a plastic bushing and a top hat retainer maybe.

Consider the spare parts diagram of a Speedplay X-series pedal. It's a lot higher end than the pedal you're referencing. However, the spindle screw holds the pedal assembly together, a bit like a stem's top cap or the retaining cap on some 2-piece cranks. Many pedals work on this principle. Some pedals (e.g. Shimano SPD and SPD-SL) don't have a bolt holding them together from the top. You undo those at the inboard end of the spindle with crescent wrenches.

If you undo your retaining bolt, you can likely disassemble the pedal. You'd be looking for a hex socket wrench like below (image from Wikipedia):

Usually you would use a hex or Torx wrench to undo the bolt, but this bolt looks like it needs a socket. You can take the pedal into a local hardware store to confirm and also to check what size you need. Or if you tighten that bolt, chances are this will take the play out - I suspect it's worked a bit loose. Anyway, if you do this, you'll probably need a metric socket.
However, children's bikes are usually built to a price point. Kids are much lighter and generate much less power than adults, so they can substitute plastic for things that ought to be metal. And anyway, even adult bikes may come with pedals that aren't designed to be serviced, as discussed in this Q&A or in the other two answers. In fact, that's more than likely to be the case for your pedals.
If they were designed to be serviced, then you might encounter some cartridge bearings inside (like the 136 and 137 bearings in the Speedplay diagram). Or you might have loose ball bearings - if that were the case, you just clean it out and put fresh grease in. You can theoretically get new ball bearings if the balls are worn. Or you might encounter plastic bushings - a bushing is a thin cylindrical tube that the shaft slides in. If that's the case, then if you could find the spare parts numbers, you could order replacements and replace them - but I don't see Wellgo list spare parts, and chances are this means you have a disposable pedal. Unless you 3D printed your own bushings or something - if someone were to go this route, I don't know what types of plastic are hard enough for this application.

I didn't downvote you, but I do feel like you're really overcomplicating the situation for a $10 pair of pedals on a kids bike. Anyways, regarding your last sentence, regular nylon would probably suffice as a bushing, but there do exist special bushing filaments that would be even better (and are surprisingly affordable).

I concluded based on the other answers that my pedals are not serviceable. I did try to fit a socket in different metric sizes to the pedal but it could not grip (as the thingy is round).
